# Query to get output as I need

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the below sample output.

```
ID_Emp| Name    |   Date          
11    |Jonh     |14/05/2014 8:16
11    |Jonh     |14/05/2014 13:35
11    |Jonh     |14/05/2014 17:23
11    |Jonh     |14/05/2014 21:09
12    |Elizabe  |14/05/2014 14:06
12    |Elizabe  |14/05/2014 20:39
12    |Elizabe  |14/05/2014 21:39
12    |Elizabe  |14/05/2014 22:39
13    |Jimmy    |14/05/2014 8:00
13    |Jimmy    |14/05/2014 17:12
13    |Jimmy    |14/05/2014 18:12
```

I
want to build a query to achieve the below results:

```
ID_Emp|Name  |Date          |TimeIn1 |TimeOut1||TimeIn2|TimeOut2|Hours
11  |Jonh    |14/05/2014    |8:16   |13:35     |17:23  |21:09  |5:19
12  |Elizabe |14/05/2014    |14:06  |20:39     |21:39  |22:39  |8:33
13  |Jimmy   |14/05/2014    |8:00   |17:12     |18:12  |  -    |9:12
```

Query:

```
SELECT cio.emp_reader_id, cio.dt AS CheckIn, 
       cio.next_dt as CheckOut
FROM (SELECT cio.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cio.emp_reader_id, CONVERT(date, cio.dt) ORDER BY cio.dt) as seqnum,
             LEAD(cio.dt) OVER (PARTITION BY cio.emp_reader_id, CONVERT(date, cio.dt) ORDER BY cio.dt) as next_dt
      FROM trnevents cio 
     ) cio 
WHERE seqnum % 2 = 1
```

Comment: Can you add the DDL and insert statements for the table to try please

Comment: Will you calculate 4 data per day.

Comment: For Elizabe hours would be 6:33 not 8:33. Hours calculate between timeout1 - timein1

Answer (score 3):

Multiple CTE is used here for calculation. This query is applicable for each date of every emp_id. Use format function for converting date and hour:minute.

```
-- SQL Server
WITH cte AS (SELECT ID_Emp
     , Name
     , CAST(tdate AS date) actual_date
     , tdate
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_Emp, CAST(tdate AS date) ORDER BY tdate) row_num
FROM test
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT ID_Emp
         , MAX(Name) Name
         , actual_date
         , MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN tdate END) TimeIn1
         , MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 2 THEN tdate END) TimeOut1
         , MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 3 THEN tdate END) TimeIn2
         , MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 4 THEN tdate END) TimeOut2
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY ID_Emp, actual_date
)
SELECT ID_Emp, Name
     , FORMAT(actual_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy') date
     , FORMAT(TimeIn1, 'HH:mm') TimeIn1
     , FORMAT(TimeOut1, 'HH:mm') TimeOut1
     , FORMAT(TimeIn2, 'HH:mm') TimeIn2
     , FORMAT(TimeOut2, 'HH:mm') TimeOut2
     , CAST((DATEDIFF(second, TimeIn1, TimeOut1)/3600) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':' +
       CAST(((DATEDIFF(second, TimeIn1, TimeOut1)%3600)/60) AS VARCHAR(2)) Hours
FROM cte2
ORDER BY ID_Emp
```

Using subquery

```
SELECT t.ID_Emp, t.Name
     , FORMAT(t.actual_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy') date
     , FORMAT(t.TimeIn1, 'HH:mm') TimeIn1
     , FORMAT(t.TimeOut1, 'HH:mm') TimeOut1
     , FORMAT(t.TimeIn2, 'HH:mm') TimeIn2
     , FORMAT(t.TimeOut2, 'HH:mm') TimeOut2
     , CAST((DATEDIFF(second, t.TimeIn1, t.TimeOut1)/3600) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':' +
       CAST(((DATEDIFF(second, t.TimeIn1, t.TimeOut1)%3600)/60) AS VARCHAR(2)) Hours
FROM (SELECT p.ID_Emp
           , MAX(p.Name) Name
           , p.actual_date
           , MAX(CASE WHEN p.row_num = 1 THEN p.tdate END) TimeIn1
           , MAX(CASE WHEN p.row_num = 2 THEN p.tdate END) TimeOut1
           , MAX(CASE WHEN p.row_num = 3 THEN p.tdate END) TimeIn2
           , MAX(CASE WHEN p.row_num = 4 THEN p.tdate END) TimeOut2
      FROM (SELECT ID_Emp
                 , Name
                 , CAST(tdate AS date) actual_date
                 , tdate
                 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_Emp, CAST(tdate AS date) ORDER BY tdate) row_num
            FROM test     
           ) p
      GROUP BY ID_Emp, actual_date) t
ORDER BY t.ID_Emp
```

Please check from this url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=54f542847167481298b168d6b0a8d6b9

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

select Id,Name,Date,TimeIn1,TimeOut1,TimeIn2
from (select Id,Name,Date,time TimeIn1,lead(a.time) over(Partition by  a.Id,a.Name,a.Date order by time) as TimeOut1
,lead(a.time,2) over(Partition by  a.Id,a.Name,a.Date order by time) as TimeIn2
,ROW_NUMBER()Over(Partition by  a.Id,a.Name,a.Date order by time) as rn
from (select Id,Name,cast(date as date) as date,cast(date as time) as Time
from Stack )a)b where rn=1